# Checking item selected from spinner

Tags: java, android

My app allows a user to name and add and item which then generates a text file (haven't coded yet). For example if they add an item named "fridge" then it generates fridge.txt. When the item is added it also gets added to an ArrayList, which is passed into my spinner. So fridge will now be seen in the spinner as well. What I need to achieve, is when the user selects an item from the spinner, it also displays data in a textview from the text file  that was generated. My question is, how can i do this if I don't know what the user named the item?

In my code below, in onItemSelected() I have a condition that checks if the value of the spinner is equal to a string, but since the user will be naming their own items how do I make my spinner do something when an item is selected?

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

String statusLink = "http://redacted.uk/pmt/status.txt";
String deviceLink = "http://redacted.uk/pmt/devices.txt";
String status;
final String degree = "\u00b0";

ArrayList<String> devicesAL = new ArrayList<>();

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    Thread thread = new Thread(new Runnable() {

        @Override
        public void run() {
            try {
                // Set up connection to device.txt on web server
                URL deviceUrl = new URL (deviceLink);
                URLConnection deviceConn = deviceUrl.openConnection();
                deviceConn.setDoOutput(true);
                deviceConn.connect();

                InputStream dis = deviceConn.getInputStream();
                InputStreamReader disr = new InputStreamReader(dis, "UTF-8");
                BufferedReader dbr = new BufferedReader(disr);

                String deviceLine;

                // Set up connection to status.txt on web server
                URL statusUrl = new URL(statusLink);
                URLConnection statusConn = statusUrl.openConnection();
                statusConn.setDoOutput(true);
                statusConn.connect();

                InputStream sis = statusConn.getInputStream();
                InputStreamReader sisr = new InputStreamReader(sis, "UTF-8");
                BufferedReader sbr = new BufferedReader(sisr);

                String statusLine;

                try {
                    while ((deviceLine = dbr.readLine()) != null) {
                        //System.out.println(deviceLine);
                        devicesAL.add(deviceLine);

                        for (String str : devicesAL) {
                            System.out.println(str);
                        }
                    }

                    while ((statusLine = sbr.readLine()) != null) {
                        System.out.println(statusLine);
                        status = statusLine;

                        System.out.println("Status = " + status);
                        TextView output = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textView);
                        System.out.println(status);
                    }

                    for (String str : devicesAL) {
                        System.out.println(str);
                    }

                    runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
                        @Override
                        public void run() {
                            //LOAD SPINNER
                            Spinner spinner = (Spinner) findViewById(R.id.spinner);
                            ArrayAdapter adp = new ArrayAdapter(MainActivity.this, android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item, devicesAL);
                            adp.setDropDownViewResource(android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item);
                            spinner.setAdapter(adp);
                            adp.notifyDataSetChanged();
                            spinner.setOnItemSelectedListener(new AdapterView.OnItemSelectedListener() {

                                @Override
                                public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {
                                    TextView output = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textView);

                                    if (parent.getItemAtPosition(position).equals("Water Cooler")) {
                                        System.out.println("Water cooler selected");
                                        output.setText(status);
                                    }
                                }

                                @Override
                                public void onNothingSelected(AdapterView<?> parent) {

                                }
                            });
                        }
                    });
                } finally {
                    sbr.close();
                }
            } catch (Exception e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
    });

    thread.start();
}
```

}

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you're trying to predict what the user will enter by using the if statement - i.e. Water Cooler. Then you're just writing out 'Water cooler selected'. If it's going to just print out what the user selected in a text box just get rid of the if statement.

```
System.out.println(parent.getItemAtPosition(position) + " selected");
output.setText(status);
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use ArrayList's method contains to see the item selected by the user in the spinner. Something just like this:

`if (devicesAL.contains(parent.getItemAtPosition(position))) {
            System.out.println(parent.getItemAtPosition(position) + " selected");
            output.setText(status);
}`